# Show that the semi-group of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\ y&1\end{bmatrix}$ with $x>0$ and $y>0$, is simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ideals, semigroups, simple-groups

Let $S=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\ y&1\end{bmatrix}: x,y\in (0,\infty)\right\}$ be a semigroup under matrix multiplication. How to prove $S$ is simple but neither left nor right simple?

the subsets of $S$ defined by the conditions $y>1$ and $y>2x$  are respectively left and right ideals. But I got stuck in proving $S$ is simple. If $\emptyset\neq T\subset S$ is an ideal we should show $T=S$. for arbitrary element $\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\ b&1\end{bmatrix}\in S$ we must prove it's an element of $T$ by using $TS\subset T$ and $ST\subset T$. I tried many matrices with no luck.

Definitions:

$\emptyset\neq T\subset S$ is said to be

- left ideal if $ST\subset T$
- right ideal if $TS\subset T$ and
- an ideal if it is both left and right ideal

$S$ is simple if it has no proper ideal.

Comment: Three upvotes for a question with zero personal input? Life is gentle sometimes...

Comment: Sorry but would you be yet another user who "forgets" to follow the rules of the site and wants to give lessons to others about votes and whatnot?

Comment: Sorry but where is all the personal input you surely hurried to add to your question as soon as I posted the comment which seems to displease you so much? I am not seeing it...

Comment: I spent a lot times for those matrices entries. I almost not  understood that my response did not take care of anyone.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1 Thank you for your answer. But I selected the answer and vote up. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following conditions are equivalent:

$\textbf{1})$ $S$ is simple semigroup.

$\textbf{2})$ $SaS=S$ for all $a\in S$.

$\textbf{3})$ for all $a,b\in S$ there exist $s,t\in S$ such that $sat=b$

$\textbf{4})$ $J=S\times S$ where  $J$ is a green  relation.

$\textbf{Note:}$ Green relation means $J$ is equivalance relation such that $aJb\iff S^1aS^1=S^1bS^1$

Above conditions can be proved easily.

I will show  condition $\textbf{2)}$ i.e., $SxS=S$ for every $x\in S$ and note that every element of $x\in S$ invertible because determinant of $x$ greater than $1$.

Let $x=\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\ b&1\end{bmatrix}\in S$ and $g,h>0$. 
If we take $d=1, e=\frac{ha}{(a+b)^2},c=g\frac{(a+b)^2}{ha}\frac{1}{a},f=\frac{hb}{a+b}$ then we obtain
$\begin{bmatrix}c&0\\ d&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&0\\ b&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}e&0\\ f&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}cae&0\\ dae+be+f&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}g\frac{(a+b)^2}{ha}\frac{1}{a}a\frac{ha}{(a+b)^2}&0\\ \frac{ha(a+b)}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{hb}{a+b}&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}g&0\\ h&1\end{bmatrix}$.

Thus for any $x\in S$, we have $SxS=S$, so $S$ is simple.